# handle '&' in url parameter DJANGO

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, urlencode

I am creating an api in django in which I have a parameter (state_name) and the value of state_name can include '&' in its value which is causing certain problems ?

For example if my url is like

```
http://localhost:8080/api?state_name=jammu&kashmir&value=2
```

so in the above example when i try to fetch the values from the url it takes the value of state_name only 'jammu' and treats kashmir as a parameter?

What can i do to resolve this issue in django ?

Comment: Is there any problem with **`jammu and kashmir`** ?

Comment: yes in my db its jammu&kasmir and to change that will be a big change?

Comment: This is actually more about URL syntax than about django. I would explain, but the answers below explain even better than I would have been able to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the `&` for use in http query parameters.

```
http://localhost:8080/api?state_name=jammu%26kashmir&value=2
```

If you're posting this from another Python script, you can use the `urllib.parse.quote` function to do it for you:

```
from urllib import parse
parse.quote("jammu&kashmir") # jammu%26kashmir
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am creating an api in django in which I have a parameter (state_name) and the value of state_name can include `'&'` in its value which is causing certain problems?

This is *nonsensical*. In a querystring, two parameters are *separated* by an ampersand (`&`). For example:

```
foo=bar&qux=3
```

If you want the *content* to contain an ampersand, you need to *encode* it, like:

```
?state_name=jammu%26kashmir&value=2
```

Here `%26` is the encoding of the ampersand, and then the *querystring* has two parameters: `state_name` and `value`. These are then parsed like:

```
>>> from django.http import QueryDict
>>> QueryDict('state_name=jammu%26kashmir&value=2')
<QueryDict: {'state_name': ['jammu&kashmir'], 'value': ['2']}>
```

You can use a `QueryDict` to construct such query, for example:

```
>>> qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
>>> qd['state_name'] = 'jammu&kashmir'
>>> qd['value'] = '2'
>>> qd.urlencode()
'state_name=jammu%26kashmir&value=2'
```